# How to list the last record in the datatable with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to always list the last records last in my datatable with jquery.

It's currently like this.

Because whenever I add a new item, the first one always appears, what is the best way to fit this pattern into my datatable with jquery

[image]

But I want to leave it set to always show the last record after inserting a new item.
[image]

DATATABLE

```
`<table id="na_datatable" class="table table-hover dashboard-task-infos">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>id</th>
                            <th>Bairro</th>
                            <th>Categoria</th>
                            <th>Apartamento</th>
                            <!--<th>Dormitórios</th>
                            <th>Box</th>
                            <th>Mobiliado</th>
                            <th>Chaves</th>
                            <th>Proprietário</th>
                            <th>Contato</th>
                            <th>Valor</th>-->
                            <th>Cadastrado em</th>
                            <th>Atualizado em</th>
                            <th>Ações</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($ci_properties as $properties) : ?>
                        <tr>
                            <th><?= $properties['propertie_id'] ?></th>
                            <th><?= $properties['bairro'] ?></th>
                            <th><?= $properties['empreendimento'] ?></th>
                            <th><?= $properties['apartamento'] ?></th>
                            <!--<th><?= $properties['dormitorios'] ?></th>
                            <th><?= $properties['box'] ?></th>
                            <th><?= $properties['mobiliado'] ?></th>
                            <th><?= $properties['chaves'] ?></th>
                            <th><?= $properties['proprietario'] ?></th>
                            <th><?= $properties['contato'] ?></th>
                            <th><?= $properties['valor'] ?></th>-->
                            <th><?= $properties['cadastro'] ?></th>
                            <th><?= $properties['atualizado'] ?></th>
                            <th> 
                                <div><a title="View" class="view btn btn-sm btn-info pull-left" data-id="<?= $properties['propertie_id'] ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-property"> Visualizar <i class="material-icons">visibility</i></a></div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                    </tbody>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>id</th>
                            <th>Bairro</th>
                            <th>Categoria</th>
                            <th>Apartamento</th>
                            <!--<th>Dormitórios</th>
                            <th>Box</th>
                            <th>Mobiliado</th>
                            <th>Chaves</th>
                            <th>Proprietário</th>
                            <th>Contato</th>
                            <th>Valor</th>-->
                            <th>Cadastrado em</th>
                            <th>Atualizado em</th>
                            <th>Ações</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
```

`

JQUERY

```
<!-- Jquery DataTable Plugin Js -->
<script src="<?= base_url()?>public/plugins/jquery-datatable/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url()?>public/plugins/jquery-datatable/skin/bootstrap/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.properties = <?= json_encode($ci_properties) ?>;
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#na_datatable').DataTable();
        $('body').on('click','.btn.view',function(e){
            var id = $(e.target).closest('.btn.view').data("id");
            var property = window.properties.find(p => p.propertie_id == id);
            $('#view-property .modal-body').html('');
            $('#view-property .modal-title .propertie-id').html(property.propertie_id);
            $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Bairro:</b> ${property.bairro}</div>`);
            $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Empreendimento:</b> ${property.empreendimento}</div>`);
            $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Apartamento:</b> ${property.apartamento}</div>`);
            $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Dormtirórios:</b> ${property.dormitorios}</div>`);
            $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Box:</b> ${property.box}</div>`);
            $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Mobiliado:</b> ${property.mobiliado}</div>`);
            $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Chaves:</b> ${property.chaves}</div>`);
            $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Proprietario:</b> ${property.proprietario}</div>`);
            $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Contato:</b> ${property.contato}</div>`);
            $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Valor:</b> ${property.valor}</div>`);
            $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Cadastro:</b> ${property.cadastro}</div>`);
            $('#view-property .modal-body').append(`<div><b>Atualizado:</b> ${property.atualizado}</div>`);
        });
    } );

</script>
```

Comment: Where are you inserting a new item in the code? You're removing everything with `.html('')`, and then just inserting one row.

Comment: You're just showing the one item that the user clicked on.

Comment: I'm leaving the html, but the stack is giving error ....

Comment: I think `$(e.target).closest('.btn.view').data("id");` should just be `$(this).data("id")`. `$(e.target)` is the `.btn.view` button that the user clicked on, and `.closest()` doesn't  include the starting element, it just looks in the containers.